# Looking for algorithms with nested loops with unpredictable iteration counts

Tags: algorithms, loops

I am working on a compiler optimisation routine for GPUs that optimises nested loops which has unpredictable number of iterations. To test my routine I need some real-life algorithms that include this kind of loop construct.

For example, there is a queue *A* with an arbitrary number of elements of type *a* each of which contains some arbitrary number of elements of type *b*. The elements of *A* should be processed in sequential order. There is no way to know beforehand how many elements of type *a* should be processed (i.e. elements could be added to *A* during it's processing), or how many *b* elements the next *a* would contain.

Such is the case of literals/clauses queue in DPLL SAT solving algorithm (that was the initial reason for developing the optimisation).

Could someone name some other algorithms that include such nested loops construct?

Comment: There are infinitely many such algorithms. Which ones do you prefer and why?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a [general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems explained there. If you are not sure how to improve your question maybe we can help you in [chat]?

Comment: For extreme cases, see [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44869/what-are-the-simplest-examples-of-programs-that-we-do-not-know-whether-they-term).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but Collatz Conjecture does not fully suit my problem since it is not some "practical" algorithm used to solve some real-life problems.
For now I use a synthetic "algorithm" with two nested loops shifting LFSRs to generate a pseudo-random stop condition. It's handy, but I need to prove my optimisation on some algorithms that solve real-life problems. For example DPLL fits because of it's usage in SAT solvers.

Comment: It is very easy to find an algorithm on the Internet by it's *purpose* or features, but it still requires a human expert answer to find an algorithm by description of it's high-level implementation.

Comment: Is simple sorting algorithm (designed for CPU of course) a good direction?

Comment: I looked into some sorting algorithms (quicksort, heapsort, sorting networks). They don't fit because there either is only one loop or the iteration count is fixed.

Comment: Insertion sort.

Comment: Insertion sort seems to fit. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome :)  BTW, you need to write @j_random_hacker (or whatever username) if you want to make sure that user gets notified of your comment.

Comment: @j_random_hacker ))